# What is a #delay inside a synchronous process used for?

Tags: verilog

I came across a synchronous process similar to this today, and immediately noticed the presence of the #delay:

```
`define dly #1

always @ (posedge fpga_sysclk_b or negedge reset_l) begin 
    if (!reset_l) begin 
        mv_in <= `dly 'h0; 
        mv_datai <= `dly 'h0; 
    end 
    else begin 
        mv_datai <= `dly mv_dataix; 
        mv_in <= `dly mv_datai; 
    end 
end
```

What does this achieve? Since the process is already synchronous to the clock, I don't understand why it is necessary.

Is this synthesizable? my understanding is that #delays are not synthesizable, is this the case in this instance too?

Answer (score 5):

This type of delay is called as **transport delay**. While using non blocking assignment, in sequential circuit, this type of delay is generally used for **modelling delay between clock and output**.

Whenever input changes, output is immediately *evaluated* and kept in a *event queue* and assigned to output after specified "transport" delay.

Of course, any type of *delay* is **not synthesizable**.

For example, lets say the following statement *executes at 5ns* timestamp.

```
always @(a,b)
  s <= #2 a+b;
```

The value of `a+b` is evaluated and stored **internally** in the **simulators event queue**, at 5ns. But the value is **not assigned** till 7ns. If any of the variables `a` or `b` *changes in the gap* of 2ns, then **again** the always block will be triggered. And another value shall be pushed into event queue.

For detailed information, [CummingsHDLCON1999_BehavioralDelays](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs152/fa06/handouts/CummingsHDLCON1999_BehavioralDelays_Rev1_1.pdf) paper is good to read. Also, the slides at [Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/jeetumistry28/delays-in-verilog) gives delay information.

Answer (score 1):

It's to simulate the clock-to-output delay.  You're correct that it's not synthesizable.